# How to get back original position of a word in a preprocessed sentence using python?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, text-processing

I am trying to get a sentence from User and preprocessing the same to remove special characters using regex at backend then I need to send back the position of a particular word in order to highlight that word to User, but facing conflict as the position of original and the preprocessed sentence are different.

Is there any best method to solve the above issue using Python?

**For example:**

```
import re

def text_preprocessing(input_text, string_to_find):

    print("Original text is:", input_data)
    cleaned_text = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9#.+]', " ", input_data)]
    cleaned_text = [re.sub(' +', " ", text) for text in cleaned_text]
    for cleaned_text in cleaned_text:  # just to convert list to string
        print("preprocessed text is:", cleaned_text)
        position = cleaned_text.find(string_to_find)
        position = [position, position + len(string_to_find)]
        return position

input_text = 'Hi! Hello'
string_to_find = 'Hello'
position = text_preprocessing(input_text, string_to_find)
print(position)
```

**Actual Output**

```
Original text is: Hi! Hello
preprocessed text is: Hi Hello
[3, 8]
```

original sentence = 'Hi! Hello'

Preprocessed sentence = 'Hi Hello' *(just removed '!' symbol)*

In case i need to highlight the word "Hello" I just returning the position from backend as **(3,8)** but the actual position in UI is **(4, 9)**

**Expected Output**

```
Original text is: Hi! Hello
preprocessed text is: Hi Hello
[4, 9]
```

---

OS: windows 10,
Python 3.7, 
used regex for preprocessing

Comment: Hi Karthikeyan, could you edit your post with an example of the code you wrote to achieve what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The first character in a string is at position `0`, then, `Hello` is at position `3` in the string `Hi Hello`.

- `H` is at `0`
- `i` is at `1`
- is at `2`
- `H` is at `3`
- `e` is at `4`
- and so on ...

Comment: @KarthikeyanSise: The instruction `position = cleaned_text.find(string_to_find)` gives the position of `Hello` in `Hi Hello` which is `3`, why would you expect `4`? If you want to have `4`, use: `position = cleaned_text.find(string_to_find) + 1`

Comment: This is sample text, I have huge text to process with lots of special character. In that case '+1' will not be helpful I hope